# bash if statement remove redundant lines

Tags: bash, if-statement

Is there a way to write the below without having to copy and paste the command multiple times?

success - it will print the "grep" to console and to the log file

failure -  it will print the " console and to the log file as well

```
  if wget -S --spider ${proxystring}"$1" 2>&1 | grep 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'; then
     wget -S --spider ${proxystring}"$1" 2>&1 | grep 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' >> $LOGFILE
     return 0;
  else
      wget -S --spider ${proxystring}"$1" 2>&1 | $TEELOG
     return 1;
  fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You only have to run the wget once.  Store the results in a temp file and work with that:

```
# Make temporary file
tmpfile=$(mktemp)

# put wget output in temp file
wget -S --spider "${proxystring}$1" 2>&1 > "$tmpfile"

# grep in temp file
grep_result=$( grep 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' "$tmpfile" )

# If string found...
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    # Append grep results to log file
    echo "$grep_result" >> $LOGFILE

    # remove temp file
    rm "$tmpfile"

    # Success!!
    return 0;

# otherwise...
else
    # put the wget results in TEELOG
    cat "$tmpfile" >> "$TEELOG"

    # remove temp file
    rm "$tmpfile"

    # Fail :(
    return 1;

fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the output in a variable then use this variable as many time as you want:

```
ret_value=`wget -S --spider ${proxystring}"$1" 2>&1 | grep 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK';`
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo $ret_value >> $LOGFILE
    return 0;
else
    wget -S --spider ${proxystring}"$1" 2>&1 | $TEELOG
    return 1;
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a special case you could take advantage of, I think. If you use `grep -v 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'`, you obviously get *no* output if the match fails, but you get *exactly* `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` if it succeeds (there's no other text on such a status line).

As such, you can unconditionally write the output of `grep` to `$TEELOG`, but hard-code the 200 response to `LOGFILE` when `grep` *fails*.

```
if ! wget -S --spider "$proxystring$1" 2>&1 | grep -v 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' | $TEELOG; then
  return 1
else
  echo 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' >> "$LOGFILE"
  return 0
fi
```

(By the way, I suspect `TEELOG` is something like `tee somefile`; use a shell function instead of a variable:

```
TEELOG () {
  tee somefile
}
```

)

Comment: `TEELOG="tee -a ${LOGFILE}"` is this not as good as a function?

Comment: No; variables are for data; functions are for code.